# Adding a new folder with displays in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I want to add a new display to rviz there are two folders I can choose from: rviz and rviz_plugin_tutorials. I want to add a new folder with new displays. How can I do that? I want to choose display from object_recognition_ros_visualization.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222578/adding-a-new-folder-with-displays-in-rviz/) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to start rviz in an environment where this package is installed / compiled and the corresponding `setup.bash` file is sourced.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-12-16**:
@sykatch: Did that resolve your question? If so, please mark it as answered. It looks like you clicked on the "accept answer" button twice ;-)